# can index html and service worker js files be placed in different folder

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker, web-performance

I placed my files as

- main

  - index.html
  - files

    - service-worker.js
    - index.js
    - mycss.css

where I wants to cache the index.js and mycss.css file which is not working. And due to some constraint, I can't put the service-worker.js in parallel to index.html page

Answer (score 2):

**Absolutely yes**. Moreover, it is considered to be a standard practice to place similar/related files in their respective folder.

So, in your `index.html` you could do something like this:

```
<body>
<script src="/files/mycss.css"></script>
<script src="/files/index.js"></script>
<script src="/files/service-worker.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach of solving the problem is to set the `Service-Worker-Allowed HTTP` response header if the scope of `service-worker.js` is different from the scope of files it wants to work with. This idea helps in applications where URL rewriting is done or the context path for files is not similar to the actual directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can put your files in different folders.
When you want to "connect" your css to the html the path is:

```
src="files/mycss.css"
```

Hope this will help you.